# Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 8888: Timed out

Tags: networking, github, docker, tcp, pip

I've been getting this Error which has made me unable to use some certain commands on my computer like pip,easy_install,even commit on github and gitbucket and this started when I tried using docker but it gave me issues. Please what can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall windows on my computer to resolve this problem. I think windows could really be a pain in the neck for developers especially those using GNU languages